# convert/clean scraped data to pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi there i have **scraped** data from website that is as below:

```
"header1","header2","header3","header4","header5":"value1-1","value1-2","value1-3","value1-4":"value2-1","   value2-2","   value2-3"," value2-4":
```

The raw data has double quotes and white spaces in between the value which i want to remove and
I want to convert the data extracted from website into pandas dataframe as below:
**Note the row ends after colon (:) in raw data

```
 header1    header2    header3    header4    header5
value1-1   value1-2   value1-3   value1-4   value1-5
value2-1   value2-2   value2-3   value2-4   value2-5
```

Please suggest me some easy fix for this

Comment: What happens to `header5`?

Comment: @anky oh sorry i forgot about header5 there are more than that but to make my question look clean i have added them as sample

Comment: No problem, understood, then you should also have values for header 5, `value1-5`,`value2-5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lineterminator` argument

```
pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=',', lineterminator=':')
```

OR

For text based input, as suggested by ***cs95***,

```
from io import StringIO
pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep=',', lineterminator=':')
```

Comment: the raw data is parsed as text not saved anywhere

Comment: @Zac if you replace `filepath` with `StringIO(your_text)` (where `StringIO` is obtained via the following import `from io import StringIO`), then it should work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have saved the string as variable `s` try:

```
a = s.split(":")
b = [i.split(",") for i in a if len(i)>0]
output_df = pd.DataFrame(b[1:],columns=b[0])
```